# Aggregate function couting times hired

Tags: sql, join, oracle11g, aggregate-functions

I'm using the HR table schema where i have an exercise stating:

The `job_history` can contain more than one entries for an employee who was hired more than once. Create a query to retrieve a list of employees that were hired more than once. Include the columns `EMPLOYEE_ID`, `LAST_NAME`, `FIRST_NAME` and the aggregate `"Times Hired"`.

What have I done so far is:

```
select e.employee_id, e.last_name, e.first_name,
       count (start_date) as Times_Hired
from job_history jH, employees e
WHERE e.employee_id=jH.employee_id
group by e.employee_id, e.last_name, e.first_name;
```

Now, my questions are:

- should the whole thing be a subquery?
- which columns connect the tables `job_history` and `employees`?

Because when I run this it displays a few employees only.

Comment: Presumably you're deleting the details on all of your questions when they're answered so that the professor can't Google for where you found them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can (and should) rewrite the query with explicit ANSI JOIN syntax to make it clear:

```
SELECT employee_id, e.last_name, e.first_name,
       count (*) AS Times_Hired
FROM   employees   e 
JOIN   job_history j USING (employee_id)
GROUP  BY employee_id, e.last_name, e.first_name
HAVING count (*) > 1;
```

<strike>I also use a `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` to include employees in the result that do not have any rows on `job_history` (yet).</strike>
This is not relevant, since you are only interested in employees ..

> than were hired more than once

I implemented this condition with `HAVING count (*) > 1`.

As to your 2nd question: obviously, `employee_id` is the column that  ..

> connects the tables `job_history` and `employees`?

Since the column name we join on (`employee_id`) is identical in both tables I simplified to an [equi-join  with `USING`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#CHDIJFDJ).

And I use `count(*)` instead of `count (start_date)`, since it has not been declared whether `start_date` can be `NULL`, in which case it wouldn't add to the count.

As to your first question: no, you don't need a subquery here.

#### Alternative `JOIN` syntax with `ON`

```
SELECT e.employee_id, e.last_name, e.first_name,
       count (*) AS Times_Hired
FROM   employees   e 
JOIN   job_history j ON j.employee_id = e.employee_id
GROUP  BY e.employee_id, e.last_name, e.first_name
HAVING count (*) > 1;
```

Tested both in [**SQLfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d5553c/1).

Comment: @user2145903: Update - Ah, my oversight! You need to remove the qualifier from *all instances* of `employee_id` once it is being used in the equi-join with `USING`. The alternative is to use a plain `ON` clause in the join. I fixed that, added the alt and bold emphasis.

Comment: @user2145903: Doesn't matter much **if** `start_date` is defined `NOT NULL` (as long as we don't use a `LEFT JOIN`) . `count(*)` might be a tiny bit faster, since only the existence of a row has to be verified. BTW: \* is a special character here in the comments, you need to escape it, for instance with \\*.